# Using definition of limit $(\epsilon - \delta)$ to prove that

Tags: multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Q) $lim_{(x, y, z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{xyz}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = 0$

Hint: $|x| \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

---

proof attempt:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon$. Then $||(x, y, z) - (0,0,0)|| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$, and so $||(x, y, z) - (0,0,0)|| < \delta$ implies that

$\left| \frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2} - 0 \right| = \frac{|xyz|}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \cdot \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \cdot \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = ||(x, y, z) - (0,0,0)|| < \delta = \epsilon$

Comment: It's just fine.

Comment: Yep, correct. Nicely done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By QM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz
$$ x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 3\,\text{GM}^2(|x|,|y|,|z|) = 3 |xyz|^{2/3}$$
hence in a pointed neighbourhood of the origin
$$ \left|\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right| \leq \tfrac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{|xyz|}$$
and the wanted limit is zero by squeezing (which makes the use of $\varepsilon/\delta$ straightforward).